# why do we need to specify startBluetoothSco if android takes care of it itself?

Tags: android, android-studio

what's the benefits of calling startBluetoothSco when android takes care of that on Androids end, and when you connect a BT headset to android the sound automatically passes to android

so why would we want to specify startBluetoothSco anyway?

is it just if we have a dedicated button to move to Bluetooth ? and then when it's pressed we can move to the headset ?

or not all android versions move to the headset automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, nothing connects to a BT SCO(hands-free profile) headset automatically. You may be thinking of A2DP (stereo profile), which does get "auto-enabled".

You may also be confused because some headsets have both profiles, and the OS  auto-switches to the A2DP one. But if you actually want to use SCO, it always has to be manually connected.